# Instance of a class using "this" keyword

Tags: instance

Why would programmers do some code like this, using the 'this' keyword

```
private Datalog instance = this;

//constructor
public Datalog() {}
```

Comment: "instance" will store the instance of current class. It must have been used internally inside this class(private) where it is written .Ur question is too abstract man

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not mention what language this is, I will assume this is Java.

In Java just as in many other languages a method (function which belongs to an instanciated object) may refer to different fields via different contexts.
meaning that sometimes in order to be able to refer to a field using the **this**.field will not be good if we want the field of a different context and not the field which belongs to the **this** (calling object).

**Follow demonstration (Note we have here a class within a class - AKA inner class):**

```
public class HumanBody{

    HumanBody instance = this;
    MainBody mb;
    int totalHeight;

    public HumanBody() {
        mb = new MainBody();
    }

    public class MainBody {

        int totalHeight;

        public int getHeightOfMainBodyOnly() {

            return instance.totalHeight - totalHeight;
        }
    }

    public int getBodyHeight() {

        return totalHeight;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: that in `getHeightOfMainBodyOnly` we do:   `instance.totalHeight - totalHeight`
when `instance.totalHeight` is the HumanBody `totalHeight` and just `totalHeight` is the MainBody total height.

We could not have done it using only this keyword, since this within `getHeightOfMainBodyOnly` will refer only to the MainBody object caller.

In Javascript this is more common, there a convention is to use:

```
var self = this;
```

also for the same reasons I mentioned here!